# Node.js Sever crashed always after 7 request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, server

I am trying to program a diary with Node. Everything works great I can add new entries as much as I want.

But for some reason I can't delete more than 7 entries. If I press delete 7 times I get no request.
When I restart the server everything works fine as if nothing had happened.

Is there something in Node where the server automatically restarts itself.

I would like the server to restart the server itself after 7 requests?

Server.js

```js
"use-strict";

const e = require('express');
const exrpress = require('express');
const app = exrpress();
const DataStore = require('nedb');
const allData = new DataStore('data.db');

allData.loadDatabase();

app.listen(3000, 'localhost', ()=>{console.log("listen at Port 3000")});
app.use(exrpress.static('public'));
app.use(exrpress.json({limit: '10mb'}));

app.get('/api', (request, response)=>{
    allData.find({},(error, data)=>{
        if(error){
            console.log(error);
            response.end();
        } else {
            response.json(data);
        }
    });
});

app.post('/api', (request, response)=>{
    console.log("I got a REQUEST ...");
    const data = request.body;

    if (Object.values(data).includes("löschen")){
        console.log("löschen");
    }else{
        const timestamp = Date.now();
        data.timestamp = timestamp;
        allData.find({datum: data.datum}, function(error, store){
            if(store.length < 1){
                allData.insert(data);
            }
        });
        response.json(data);
    }
});
```

Class.js

```js
"use-strict";

class Eintrag{
    constructor(list){
        this.list = list;
    }

    neue_liste = function(neuer_Eintrag){
        let wahr = false;
        for(let element of this.list){
            if (Object.values(element).includes(neuer_Eintrag.datum)){
                alert(`Zu diesem Datum: '${neuer_Eintrag.datum}' gibt es bereits einen Eintrag!`);
                wahr = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(!wahr){
            this.list.push(neuer_Eintrag);
        }
    }

    html_generieren = function(element){
        const html = 
        `
        <div class="eintrag_container">
            <span class="datum">${element.datum}</span>
            <button timestamp ="${element.timestamp}">Löschen</button>
            <p>
                ${element.data}
            </p>
        </div>
        `;

        return html;
    }

    eintrag_anzeigen = function(){
        document.querySelectorAll("#alle_container > .eintrag_container").forEach(element => element.remove());
        for(const element of this.list){
            document.querySelector("#alle_container").insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", this.html_generieren(element));
        }
        löschen();
    };

    ausgabe = function(){
        console.log(this.list);
    }

    eintrag_löschen(timestamp){
        for (let i = 0; i< this.list.length; i++){
            if(this.list[i].timestamp == timestamp){
                this.list.splice(i, 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Main.js

```js
"use-strict";

const Tagebuch = new Eintrag([]);

const löschen = function(){
    let timestamp;
    let wahr = false;
    document.querySelectorAll(".eintrag_container > button").forEach(button => {
        button.addEventListener("click", async (data) => {
            wahr = true;
            timestamp = button.getAttribute("timestamp");
            Tagebuch.eintrag_löschen(timestamp);
            Tagebuch.eintrag_anzeigen();
            Tagebuch.ausgabe();
            await fetch('/api', daten_eintrag(timestamp, "löschen"));
        });
    });
}

const daten_eintrag = function(data, action){
    let eintrag ; 
    switch(action){
        case "hinzufügen":  eintrag = {datum: data.target.elements.datum.valueAsDate, eintrag: data.target.elements.eintrag.value};
                            break;
        case "löschen":     eintrag = {timestamp: data, action:"löschen"};
                            break;
        default:            alert("Es ist ein Fehler aufgetreten!"); break;
    }

    return {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {"Content-type": "application/json"},
        body: JSON.stringify(eintrag),
    }
}

const senden = async function(neu_eintrag){
    try{
        const response = await fetch('/api', daten_eintrag(neu_eintrag, "hinzufügen"));
        const daten = await response.json();
        const option = {year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: '2-digit'};
        Tagebuch.neue_liste({
            datum: new Date(daten.datum).toLocaleDateString('de-DE',option),
            data: daten.eintrag,
            timestamp: daten.timestamp
        });
        Tagebuch.eintrag_anzeigen();
        //console.log(daten);
    } catch(error){
        alert("Es ist ein Fehler aufgetreten!");
    }
}

const hole_eintrag = async function(){
    try{
        const response = await fetch('/api');
        const data = await response.json();
        const option = {year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: '2-digit'};

        for(liste of data){

            Tagebuch.neue_liste({
                    datum: new Date(liste.datum).toLocaleDateString('de-DE',option),
                    data: liste.eintrag,
                    timestamp: liste.timestamp
                }
            );
        }
        Tagebuch.eintrag_anzeigen();
    } catch(error){
        alert("Es ist ein Fehler aufgetreten!")
    }
}

hole_eintrag();

document.querySelector("#formular").addEventListener("submit", (data)=>{
    data.preventDefault();
    senden(data);
    data.target.reset();
});
```

---

Comment: How are you deleting? I don't see any `app.delete` route? Are you talking about client side delete in `Class.js`?

Comment: threre i don t delete i only checked, if i get a request

Comment: I didn't get you, you said "But for some reason I can't delete more than 7 entries. If I press delete 7 times I get no request. ", and above you're saying you don't. Also if possible please convert names in your code to **English** so that its easier for folks here to help you.

Comment: in nodejs file i only check if i get a request. sry i fargot the html file there i have button which sends a request to my server to delete. and 7 time i get a request, but after i dont. whren i rerun the server it works

Comment: Sorry I'm repeating myself, you said "which sends a request to my server to delete", that's why I wanted to understand where is the `delete` method in your code? Also please update the question with the `HTML` file as well.

Comment: are you saying that after clicking delete (`Löschen`) 7 times, you no longer see `"I got a REQUEST ..."` on the server, and restarting the server fixes that issue? when you restart the server do you also refresh the web page?